# Series identical power supplies

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, series

Recently I made a thread about parallel supplies, however my helper fried one of them... Wonderful.

So I got myself 4 of the famous DPS-1200FB-1 12v 100A power supplies. So I am an electronics noob, hence my name. I know the issue with parallel supplies is current sharing, but I don’t see anything wrong with putting all 4 12v power supplies in series to get 48v at 100A.

I am still not clear with what galvanic isolation is. I believe it is making power supplies so the ground wires aren’t touching each other or something like that.

So could I put these 4 PSUs in series to get 48v at 100A? Do I need to float them? What if I don’t float them?

I cannot find a datasheet for these, but I bought them from [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/372802558916)

Comment: How about a link to the datasheet for the famous DPS-1200FB-1 12v 100A power supply? Pop a neat hyperlink into your question where it belongs rather than in the comments.

Comment: I cannot find a datasheet for these, however, I can link the place where I got them. I got them here. https://www.ebay.com/itm/372802558916

Comment: Without a real datasheet it is hard to be confident about doing something like this. Maybe the lesson here is to always buy from professional sources that supply all necessary documentation.

Comment: hold a AA cell in each hand ... those two cells are galvanically isolated ... you can touch any terminal to any other terminal without an issue .... now, run a wire from the negative terminal of each AA cell to a common ground point ... now you have something similar to two non-galvanically isolated power supplies

Comment: @jsotola What is your point? The OP didn't propose using AA cells.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, sorry, i was not finished typing and i accidetally hit "return" .... the OP indicated being unsure what galvanic isolatation means

Comment: You can put them in series as long you don't go above the rating for the Y caps used to connect DC and PE.

Comment: @Janka, you could use relay contacts for the PE signal

Comment: What are y caps and pe signals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Galvanically isolated means there is no DC coupling between the input and output.

Here is the best step by step on how to remove the ground strap on all except the 1st supply. Then add a bus resistor to enable the supply.

https://www.rchelination.com/index.php/tech-tips/how-to-setting-up-the-hp-dps-1200fb-power-supply

Y caps are line to ground used for line noise EMI filters.

PE is the Protective Earth ground.

Comment: So if I just didn’t ground 3 of them, it would work? Saying that all of the supplies are and enabled.

I have seen those little ceramic caps in power supplies and always wondered what they were for.

Comment: That's the idea. But there may be other concerns on power sequencing or simultaneous with surges on input.

Comment: Well, the neutral wire goes to the same place in an electrical panel, so it would seem as if the neutral would prevent those things.

Comment: PE is removed on PS2,3,4 but cascaded on DC side. Line/neutral shared on all

Comment: Cascaded on dc side?

Comment: cascaded = series of elements

Comment: So you are saying I would need to add the ground back to the dc side somehow?

Comment: I was say the chassis PE needs to be removed on all except PS1  . Go read