# Floating Power Supplies

Tags: power-supply, floating

Referring to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470896/series-identical-power-supplies) post, is it possible to float power supplies by simply not connecting the ground wire?

Comment: not connecting the ground wire to what?

Comment: To the power supply.

Comment: @jsotola OP probably wants to float his power supply in the same way some people want to float an oscilloscope. The answer is no you cannot float a power supply by just not connecting the ground wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safety ground is used for other purposes as well as keeping the frame at 0V.

1) attenuate bidirectional noise thru chokes and Y caps to PE Gnd.

2) reduce accumulated insulated charge for high power leakage currents and accumulated voltage to reduce stress for breakdown voltage.

The other question referred to isolating the secondary DC from PE.